# New GitHub Push to Master -> Zip it Up, Send it to S3

Tags: php, json, wordpress, github, amazon-s3

I'm looking to do pretty much what the title says.

I'm using a PHP auto-updater for a WordPress plugin, and what I can do is simply update a JSON file remotely and everyone with the plugin will get an update to install the new upgrade. Pretty sweet.

To streamline things, though, I'd like to be able to simply have the JSON file be update automatically; this means that every time there's a new push to `master` on GitHub, that code will be zipped and uploaded to S3; then *that* S3 link will be updated in the JSON file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Use the Github [POST-Receive-Hook](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/) and insert a URL to a PHP script that will fetch the new data via `exec` and `git pull origin master`, zips it and pushes it up to S3.

Then update the JSON file with `file_(get|put)_contents` and `json_(en|de)code`. Afterwards commit it with `git commit -a -m "Message"` and `git push` it.

Comment: Good answer, however just want to put this out there that you can use `git archive --format=zip` to automatically archive the project and zip it.

Comment: DUDE, thank you so much! I'll work with this and try to set it up, I'll let you know how everything goes.

Comment: Hey Tim, do you have any links to tutorials that explain this further or explore it in greater detail? Thanks.

Comment: @ggwicz No, I don't. Everything I know was linked in my answer.

Comment: Github has since closed their Downloads tab, they no longer provide a blank check of file hosting.